# Java Table model remove row ArrayOutOfBounds -1

Tags: java, swing, jtable, indexoutofboundsexception

I am trying to delete the selected row from a JTable, but it gives me some exception :

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
```

This is my code :

```
private JTable table;
private DefaultTableModel model;

model = new MyTableModel();
table = new JTable(model);

table.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener(){
            public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e){
                //Here it enables my delete button as i set it to enabled false at create
            }
        });
model.removeRow(table.getSelectedRow());
```

This is MyTableModel class :

```
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class MyTableModel extends DefaultTableModel {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column){  
        return false;  
    }
}
```

I insert values in the table, modify them and i also want to delete some. Everything works, except for deleting.

Comment: `model.removeRow(table.getSelectedRow());` "appears" to be out side of the `ListSelectionListener` or any other control mechanism, so maybe `table.getSelectedRow()` is returning `-1`, meaning that nothing is selected

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses